# Создать php цикл

Tags: php, парсер, циклы, if

php цикл обхода пагинации на сайте, при помощи html парсера (называется DiDOM, но не суть)

```
// Страница входа в каталог
$pagin = 'https://www.site.ru/catalog/';

while ($pagin = $pagin)
{
    if (empty($pagin)) {
        break;
    }
// Заходим в каталог
$document = new Document($pagin, true, $encoding);

// Обходим пагинацию непосредственно
$pagin = $document->find('span.cur')[0]->nextSibling('a.dark_link::attr(href)')->attr('href');

// Перезаписываем значение url страницы на следующую страницу пагинации
$pagin = "$pagin";

}
```

Цикл работает, значения страниц извлекает, но, когда пагинация заканчивается, получаем fatal error, тк объекты обхода заканчиваются. Не могу понять, как завершить цикл, мой break на проверку пустого значения получаемой ссылки пагинации не срабатывает

Comment: если у вас fatal error, то следует почитать почему он произошёл и на какой строчке. А потом подумать и исправить код

Comment: я же указал - fatal error возникает на строке получения пагинации, потому, что пагинация заканчивается, а цикл пытается ее искать. Мне нужно как то прервать выполнения цикла в случае, когда элемент поиска отсутствует

Comment: в коде нет получения пагинации. Есть код получения ссылки из html документа. И вы опять таки не написали текст ошибки fatal error

Comment: ссылки пагинации мы получаем с помощью переобхода страниц, посещая каждую следующую страницу пагинации и забирая ее url. Но когда приходим на последнюю страницу каталога, где ссылки на след. страницу пагинации больше нет, то получаем "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function attr() on null". А нужно что бы цикл завершался корректно, без ошибок. Стоит отметить, что в этом вопросе я плохо разбираюсь, поэтому код может быть не слишком адекватным) отсюда и вопросы

Comment: понял, что ошибку, которую выдает именно парсер DiDOM, нужно как то отладить. Возникает она, как выше говорил, изза отсутствия искомого им следующего элемента пагинации, и не реагирует на empty, все равно выдает ошибку. А вот как с этим бороться, знать может, полагаю, только человек разбирающийся непосредственно с DiDOM, а таких я тут не видел (задавая пару вопросов по нему ранее)

Comment: исключительно по коду ошибки.  `$a = $document->find('span.cur')[0]->nextSibling('a. ::attr(href)'); if ($a) $pagin = $a->attr('href'); else break;`

Comment: и можно просто `while (True)`

Comment: @splash58 супер! Отрабатывает без ошибок, спасибо! Если оформите отдельным ответом, отмечу как решение

Comment: а если еще немного модифицировать, и предусмотреть отсутствие первого селектора $document->find('span.cur')[0]->nextSibling. Сейчас, если его вдруг не окажется на странице, получим "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function nextSibling() on null". Как этого избежать, не подскажите пример?

Comment: вы можете весь цикл обернуть в try catch

Comment: @splash58 спасибо за совет, получилось! Правда иногда try catch уходит в бесконечность, если ошибка в $document = new Document($pagin, true, $encoding);, при передаче параметра $pagin, не могу понять почему..